# count, for a list of date, how many time intervals contains a date

Tags: r, purrr, dateinterval

I could not solve this issue even after looking at several answers on stack overflow.
I have a dataset with a list of dates and a list of intervals.
I need to find how many intervals contains a date, for that given date.
I could find several question on how many date were contained in a interval, but this is not what i am looking for.

Here is a reproducible example

```
d<-data.frame(ID=c(80, 736, 54, 259, 826, 446, 950, 841, 433, 518, 1357, 
     3686, 4042, 749, 2716, 4568, 1424, 332, 1000, 575, 1815, 3074, 
     3768, 932, 4, 3872, 2033, 2495, 3310), 
     date=ymd(c("2022-02-20", "2022-02-21", "2022-02-22", "2022-02-23", "2022-02-24", 
         "2022-02-25", "2022-02-26", "2022-02-27", "2022-02-28", 
         "2022-03-01", "2022-03-02", "2022-03-02", "2022-03-03", "2022-03-04", 
         "2022-03-05", "2022-03-05", "2022-03-06", "2022-03-07", "2022-03-08", 
         "2022-03-09", "2022-03-10", "2022-03-10", "2022-03-10", "2022-03-11", 
         "2022-03-12", "2022-03-12", "2022-03-13", "2022-03-13", "2022-03-13")),
     start.date= ymd(c( NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "2022-03-02", "2022-03-02", 
                       "2022-03-03", "2022-03-04", "2022-03-05", "2022-03-05", "2022-03-06", 
                       NA, "2022-03-08", "2022-03-09", "2022-03-10", "2022-03-10", "2022-03-10", 
                       NA, "2022-03-12", "2022-03-12", "2022-03-13", "2022-03-13", "2022-03-13")),
      end.date=ymd(c( NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "2022-03-15", "2022-03-10", 
                     "2022-03-07", "2022-03-14", "2022-03-29", "2022-03-17", "2022-03-21", 
                     NA, "2022-03-27", "2022-03-16", "2022-03-16", "2022-03-24", "2022-03-18", 
                     NA, "2022-03-22", "2022-03-18", "2022-03-22", "2022-03-30", "2022-03-19"
      )))

d<-d %>% mutate(interval=(start.date %--% end.date)) %>% select(-start.date,-end.date)
```

what I would like to get is, in a new column, for each date, the number of interval containing the date.

I normally use dplyr-lubridate, I tried to solve this with purrr but was not able to succeed.
Any suggestion?
Thank you
EDIT:i tried with a purrr solution like the following
`d %>% mutate(dates_in_intv = map_int(interval, function(x) sum(.$date %within% x)))`
which is counting over how many dates an interval is spanning, but what I need would be something like
`d %>% mutate(intv_contains_dates= map_int(date, function(x) sum(.$interval "contains" x)))`

Comment: I don't understand _"the number of interval containing the date"_, could you explain it better? Best by showing the expected output.

Comment: thank you, i tried to better explain it now with an edit of the main question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(ivs)

d <- data.frame(
  ID = c(
    80, 736, 54, 259, 826, 446, 950, 841, 433, 518, 1357,
    3686, 4042, 749, 2716, 4568, 1424, 332, 1000, 575, 1815, 3074,
    3768, 932, 4, 3872, 2033, 2495, 3310
  ),
  date = ymd(c(
    "2022-02-20", "2022-02-21", "2022-02-22", "2022-02-23", "2022-02-24",
    "2022-02-25", "2022-02-26", "2022-02-27", "2022-02-28",
    "2022-03-01", "2022-03-02", "2022-03-02", "2022-03-03", "2022-03-04",
    "2022-03-05", "2022-03-05", "2022-03-06", "2022-03-07", "2022-03-08",
    "2022-03-09", "2022-03-10", "2022-03-10", "2022-03-10", "2022-03-11",
    "2022-03-12", "2022-03-12", "2022-03-13", "2022-03-13", "2022-03-13"
  )),
  start.date = ymd(c(
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "2022-03-02", "2022-03-02",
    "2022-03-03", "2022-03-04", "2022-03-05", "2022-03-05", "2022-03-06",
    NA, "2022-03-08", "2022-03-09", "2022-03-10", "2022-03-10", "2022-03-10",
    NA, "2022-03-12", "2022-03-12", "2022-03-13", "2022-03-13", "2022-03-13"
  )),
  end.date = ymd(c(
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "2022-03-15", "2022-03-10",
    "2022-03-07", "2022-03-14", "2022-03-29", "2022-03-17", "2022-03-21",
    NA, "2022-03-27", "2022-03-16", "2022-03-16", "2022-03-24", "2022-03-18",
    NA, "2022-03-22", "2022-03-18", "2022-03-22", "2022-03-30", "2022-03-19"
  ))
)

d %>% 
  mutate(iv = iv(start.date, end.date),
         count = iv_count_between(date, iv))
#>      ID       date start.date   end.date                       iv count
#> 1    80 2022-02-20       <NA>       <NA>                 [NA, NA)     0
#> 2   736 2022-02-21       <NA>       <NA>                 [NA, NA)     0
#> 3    54 2022-02-22       <NA>       <NA>                 [NA, NA)     0
#> 4   259 2022-02-23       <NA>       <NA>                 [NA, NA)     0
#> 5   826 2022-02-24       <NA>       <NA>                 [NA, NA)     0
#> 6   446 2022-02-25       <NA>       <NA>                 [NA, NA)     0
#> 7   950 2022-02-26       <NA>       <NA>                 [NA, NA)     0
#> 8   841 2022-02-27       <NA>       <NA>                 [NA, NA)     0
#> 9   433 2022-02-28       <NA>       <NA>                 [NA, NA)     0
#> 10  518 2022-03-01       <NA>       <NA>                 [NA, NA)     0
#> 11 1357 2022-03-02 2022-03-02 2022-03-15 [2022-03-02, 2022-03-15)     2
#> 12 3686 2022-03-02 2022-03-02 2022-03-10 [2022-03-02, 2022-03-10)     2
#> 13 4042 2022-03-03 2022-03-03 2022-03-07 [2022-03-03, 2022-03-07)     3
#> 14  749 2022-03-04 2022-03-04 2022-03-14 [2022-03-04, 2022-03-14)     4
#> 15 2716 2022-03-05 2022-03-05 2022-03-29 [2022-03-05, 2022-03-29)     6
#> 16 4568 2022-03-05 2022-03-05 2022-03-17 [2022-03-05, 2022-03-17)     6
#> 17 1424 2022-03-06 2022-03-06 2022-03-21 [2022-03-06, 2022-03-21)     7
#> 18  332 2022-03-07       <NA>       <NA>                 [NA, NA)     6
#> 19 1000 2022-03-08 2022-03-08 2022-03-27 [2022-03-08, 2022-03-27)     7
#> 20  575 2022-03-09 2022-03-09 2022-03-16 [2022-03-09, 2022-03-16)     8
#> 21 1815 2022-03-10 2022-03-10 2022-03-16 [2022-03-10, 2022-03-16)    10
#> 22 3074 2022-03-10 2022-03-10 2022-03-24 [2022-03-10, 2022-03-24)    10
#> 23 3768 2022-03-10 2022-03-10 2022-03-18 [2022-03-10, 2022-03-18)    10
#> 24  932 2022-03-11       <NA>       <NA>                 [NA, NA)    10
#> 25    4 2022-03-12 2022-03-12 2022-03-22 [2022-03-12, 2022-03-22)    12
#> 26 3872 2022-03-12 2022-03-12 2022-03-18 [2022-03-12, 2022-03-18)    12
#> 27 2033 2022-03-13 2022-03-13 2022-03-22 [2022-03-13, 2022-03-22)    15
#> 28 2495 2022-03-13 2022-03-13 2022-03-30 [2022-03-13, 2022-03-30)    15
#> 29 3310 2022-03-13 2022-03-13 2022-03-19 [2022-03-13, 2022-03-19)    15
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

And a purrr approach:

```
period_df <- d |> 
  select(start.date, end.date) |> 
  drop_na(start.date) 

map2_dfr(period_df$start.date, period_df$end.date, function(x, y) {
  
  d |> 
    distinct(date) |> 
    mutate(count = if_else(date >= x & date <= y, 1, 0))
}) |> 
  group_by(date) |> 
  summarise(count = sum(count)) |> 
  arrange(desc(count))
```

Comment: Hi Carl, Thank you for you answer! I see with this solution I can identify if the date is between the corresponding interval (start.date,end.date) on the same row, and count how many time time this is true. What I actually need is for each date to loop over all the interavls (all the pairs start.date-end.date) of the column, and count in how many intervals the date is present). This is why I was looking at a purrr solution (or maybe a for loop).

Comment: I tried to better explain it now with an edit of the main question

Comment: Does this update do what you need?

Comment: YES! Thank you! This is what I was looking for !!I was not aware of the ivs package, I will study it. I wonder whether there was also a purrr solution, but the ivs package seems to work fine! I marked the question as solved!

Comment: I've added a purrr approach too.